# Changing Hashcode in runtime

Tags: java, hashmap

Everybody knows that it's better to use an immutable class as key in `HashMap`, and if we change object state then the JVM recalculates the hash code for that object.

Can someone make example where after changing the state of an object its hashcode changes? (in runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Something {

    public String blah;

    public int hashCode() {
        return blah.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Obviously you wouldn't quite code things like this (you'd have a getter and a setter, and the `hashCode` would be a little more complicated, and you'd have an `equals()` too) but this meets the requirements of your question. If you change the `blah` field, then the hash code will change.

Comment: It works, but if i will not override hashcode(), can state changes affect the return value(hashcode)?

Comment: If it inherits `Object.hashCode()` then a state change won't affect the return value because the return value is just based on location in memory. If it extends some other class that overrides `.hashCode()` then it'll depend on what that class is doing.

Comment: it turns out that the use of Object.hashCode() better?  Why we need override hashcode() in  that case?

Comment: @IGRZXC because hash maps and the like rely on two instances that are equal (according to .equals()) having the same hash code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an object of the following class in a HashMap, and call setState while it's in the map, you will have problems.

```
Class MutableExample {
    private int state;

    public void setState(int s) {
        state = s;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return state;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof MutableExample)) {
            return false;
        }

        return ((MutableExample) o).state == state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `Person` class is mutable, and `hashCode` and `equals` are computed based on two properties - `firstName` and `lastName`.

```
Person p1 = new Person ("John", "Smith");
Person p2 = new Person ("John", "Doe");
Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
persons.add (p1);
System.out.println(persons.contains(p2)); // prints false
p2.setLastName("Smith");
System.out.println(persons.contains(p2)); // prints true
```

And even worse :

```
Person p1 = new Person ("John", "Smith");
Person p2 = new Person ("John", "Doe");
Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
persons.add (p1);
System.out.println(persons.contains(p2)); // prints false
persons.add (p2);
p2.setLastName("Smith");
System.out.println(persons.size()); // prints 2
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2)); // prints true
```

The `HashSet` is broken - it contains two equal instances.

The same example would apply for `HashMap`s where the key is `Person`.